# imagemagick read image from memory C#

Tags: c#, imagemagick, memorystream

So we have public class which pass image there named string fileName, I need to use MaigickImage with MemoryStream or byte[] because this is a web, there is no point in the address to the file. Somehow I need to pass string fileName into MemoryStream and then pass it to MagickImage. When I am using new MagickImage("fileName") it gave me error such no file or dirrectiry found. So I need it to pass thru MemoryStream or byte[] without using MagickImage("fileName")

```
        private void Update(ClientFileType type, FileData newFile, int clientId, string fileName)
        {


using (var image = new MagickImage("fileName"))
{
    // Save frame as jpg
    image.Write("fileName");
}

// Write to stream
var settings = new MagickReadSettings();
// Tells the xc: reader the image to create should be 800x600
settings.Width = 800;
settings.Height = 600;

using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    // Create image that is completely purple and 800x600
    using (var image = new MagickImage("xc:purple", settings))
    {
        // Sets the output format to png
        image.Format = MagickFormat.Png;

        // Write the image to the memorystream
        image.Write(memStream);
    }
}

// Read image from file
using (var image = new MagickImage("fileName"))
{
    // Sets the output format to jpeg
    image.Format = MagickFormat.Jpeg;

    // Create byte array that contains a jpeg file
    byte[] data = image.ToByteArray();
}

            var currentFiles = 
                _clientFileService.Value.GetFilesByClient(clientId).Where(x => x.ClientFileType == type).Select(x => x.Id).ToList();

            _clientFileService.Value.MultipleDelete(currentFiles, null);

            _clientFileService
                .Value
                .AddFile(
                new ClientFile
                {
                    FileName = fileName,
                    Guid = Guid.NewGuid()
                });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Mock implementation of what you desire, please check if it helps you.
I just followed ImageMagick documentation to figure out what you have to do. I cannot fully test due to being specific to your service implementation.

Edit #1 Explanation:
All I'm doing is creating a MemoryStream and passing into ImageMagick before doing any processing whatsoever. Instead of accessing files on disk, we just access memory.

```
private void MockUpdate(ClientFileType type, FileData newFile, int clientId, string fileName)
        {
            // Create settings
            var settings = new MagickReadSettings();

            // Let's use 800x600 with format PNG
            settings.Width = 800;
            settings.Height = 600;
            settings.Format = MagickFormat.Png;

            // Buffer where we are saving the result of saving the image
            byte[] imageBuffer = null;

            // Let's create a memory stream
            using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Pass the memory stream and settings into MagickImage
                using (var image = new MagickImage(memStream, settings))
                {
                    // Write the image to the memorystream
                    image.Write(memStream);

                    // Get the data into the buffer
                    imageBuffer = image.ToByteArray();
                }
            }

            var currentFiles =
                _clientFileService.Value.GetFilesByClient(clientId).Where(x => x.ClientFileType == type).Select(x => x.Id).ToList();

            _clientFileService.Value.MultipleDelete(currentFiles, null);

            _clientFileService
                .Value
                .AddFile(
                new ClientFile
                {
                    FileName = fileName,
                    Guid = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    image = imageBuffer // save the raw data here as a blob
                });
        }

        private byte[] MockProcess(ClientFileType type, int clientId, string fileName)
        {
            // Use service to load buffer with clientId and fileName
            byte[] bufferImage = service.GetImageWithClientId(clientId, fileName);

            // Let's create a memory stream
            using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Pass the memory stream and settings into MagickImage
                using (var image = new MagickImage(memStream))
                {
                    DoMyProcessing(image);
                }
            }
        }


        private byte[] MockLoadImage(ClientFileType type, int clientId, string fileName)
        {
            // Use service to load buffer with clientId and fileName
            byte[] bufferImage = service.GetImageWithClientId(clientId, fileName);

            return bufferImage;
        }
```

Comment: I fixed it by passing from another method that been stored in system

Answer (score 0):

Please check the official [documentation](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/blob/main/docs/ReadingImages.md) on the .NET library.

As of 27/12/2021, for the sake of example, here is a sample of the documentation on how to do this. Hope this is helpful!

```
// Read from stream.
using (var memStream = LoadMemoryStreamImage())
{
    using (var image = new MagickImage(memStream))
    {
    }
}

// Read from byte array.
var data = LoadImageBytes();
using (var image = new MagickImage(data))
{
}
```

I suggest you do something like :

1. Load the file/content into a byte array
2. Pass the byte array into the stream
3. Pass the stream into the MagicImage constructor.

Comment: I still can't get it. I am passing it with byte array, but it still not working

Comment: i cant find LoadMemoryStreamImage() and LoadImageBytes() methods

Comment: [Here is a direct sample from the documentation on how to do what you desire.](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/blob/3b22c0436037cc3fdc11ff835675c7e55e9a6e21/samples/Magick.NET.Samples/ReadImage.cs)


Please take note on the very first two methods, they are custom-made for this sample, so you may have to adapt as you wish.

Comment: still, there are plenty thing that not work for me. I have byte array, but when i am trying it implement it stay can\t be used in MagicImage, so my string fileName is byte array